# How do I save an image via imgproc? [Raspberry Pi]

Tags: python, pi-2

I am creating a project with python and **Raspberry Pi**. I am trying to use my Webcam, as I, unfortunately burned my Camera Module. I was following along: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/image_processing/

Everything is working fine, except for one problem. I am not able to save the image file that is captured. I would like to take the photo I have created and turn it into a .jpg image. Code I have currently:

```
from imgproc import *
import cv2

# open the webcam
my_camera = Camera(320, 240)
# grab an image from the camera
my_image = my_camera.grabImage()

# open a view, setting the view to the size of the captured image
my_view = Viewer(my_image.width, my_image.height, "ETSBot Look")

# display the image on the screen
my_view.displayImage(my_image)

# wait for 5 seconds, so we can see the image
waitTime(0)
```

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!
-Saurish Srivastava

Custom Library (The imgproc I used)https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/downloads/